# Trying to copy denedecy bot not working

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>eau-claims-jar</artifactId>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<name>eau-claims-jar</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>2.1.10.0-TIM3-SNAPSHOT</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-4-eau</id>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- <version>2.10</version> -->
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>kcaps</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.3.0.0-TIM2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                        <!-- <type>jar</type> -->
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Dependent kcaps jar is not getting downloaded. I am trying to build a jenkins job that downloads the dependent jar and copy to the server. Only eau-claims-jar jar is getting generated and copied but the dependent jar is not. any idea what i am doing wrong or any different approach?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.egtry.com/tools/maven/dependency_copy
Tried how its in above link and it worked. still don't understand what was the issue with my pom.xml